# Switching from game to menu then back creates lag

Tags: menu, pygame, restart, lag

The game starts out working at the right speed. However, when I press escape and go back to the main menu, and then go back to the game, the game creates a little lag (same with when I get game over screen and then go back to main menu and start the game). When I keep doing that over and over again, it creates more and more lag.

In more "coding" terms, when I press Start on the menu, it calls reset(), which resets the positions of all the sprites. When there is a Game over, it shows the game over screen, and then the user presses escape to go back to the menu.

```
menuOn = 1
Rooms = []
running = True #Flags game as on
screen = None
(x1, y1) = (0, 0)
(x2, y2) = (0, -screenHeight)
allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def placeholder1(screen):
    Rooms = []
    Rooms.append(Room())
    global menuOn
    menuOn = 0
    pass

class Menu(object):
    def __init__(self,screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.title = startMenu
        self.menu = genmenu(['START', lambda: placeholder1(screen)],['INFO', lambda: placeholder2(screen)], ['QUIT', lambda: quit()])
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        event = pygame.event.get()
        self.menu.create(self.screen)
        self.menu.choose(event)
        self.main_loop()

    def main_loop(self):
        while menuOn == 1:
            self.clock.tick(60)
            events = pygame.event.get()
            self.menu.choose(events)
            self.screen.blit(self.title, (0, 0))
            self.menu.create(self.screen)
            pygame.display.flip()

class Room():
    def __init__(self):
        global wall, player, redFish, redfishes, greenFish, greenfishes, sharks, shark
        for x in range(29):
            wall = Wall()
            wall.rect.topleft = (x*32,0) #top walls
            walls.append(wall)
        for x in range(29):
            wall = Wall()
            wall.rect.topleft = (x*32,screenHeight-32) #bottom walls
            walls.append(wall)
        for y in range(17):
            wall = Wall()
            wall.rect.topleft = (0, (y*32)+32) #left walls
            walls.append(wall)
        for y in range(17):
            wall = Wall()
            wall.rect.topleft = (screenWidth-32, (y*32)+32) #right walls
            walls.append(wall)
        reset()
def reset():
    global playerpos
    playerpos = [screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2]
    player.rect.topleft = (playerpos[0], playerpos[1])
    for greenFish in greenfishes:
        greenFish.image = images["spr_greenfish"]
        greenScoreList[greenfishes.index(greenFish)] = 0
        greenFish.rect.topleft = random.randint(35,screenWidth-80),random.randint(35,screenHeight-80)
    for redFish in redfishes:
        redFish.rect.topleft = random.randint(35,screenWidth-80),random.randint(35,screenHeight-80)
    sharks[0].rect.topleft = (100, 500)
    sharks[1].rect.topleft = (300, 500)
    sharks[2].rect.topleft = (500, 500)
    sharks[3].rect.topleft = (700, 500)
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    if menuOn == 1:
        Menu(screen)
    elif menuOn == 2:
        GameOver(screen)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                updateScoreToScreen(score)
                menuOn = 1
                reset()
    allsprites.update()
    screen.blit(ground, (0,screenHeight-100))
    allsprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: It sounds like you're creating objects each time without deleting them causing it to bog the system down. More than likely all of those wall objects. Are they getting recreated each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment, the solution is to put:
    global walls
    walls = []
in the function placeholder1. Thank you!